# Autocad.net Get Line and Make line by it

Tags: c#, .net, autocad-plugin

I've got something like following code:

```
var trat = doc.Database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
blort = trat.GetObject(blott[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;

List<Line> nieuwelijnen = new List<Line>(); 
Point3dCollection punten = new Point3dCollection();
foreach (ObjectId id in set.GetObjectIds())
{
  Entity ent = trat.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead) as Entity;
  breaklijn.IntersectWith(ent, Intersect.OnBothOperands, punten, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

  if (ent.GetType() == typeof(Line))
    {
    Line tijdelijk = trat.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead) as Line;
    Line tijdelijk1 = new Line(tijdelijk.startpoint, punten[0]);
    nieuwelijnen.Add(tijdelijk1);
    }
}

int iaantal = nieuwelijnen.Count();
for(int i = 0; i < iaantal; i++ )
  {
  blort.AppendEntity(nieuwelijnen[i]);
  }

trat.Commit();
```

At first it seems to work fine, what means, when I follow by 'watches', properties and stuff seem to be set right, right startpoint, right endpoint, works ok.

however, it stucks on the trat.commit(), not giving any errors or such, but neither adding the lines to my autocad.

then, when opening the watches, there are some runtime errors in the lines, so expect the mistake to be in the 'Line tijdelijk = trat.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead) as Line;'. however not sure of it. must be some dumb mistake but can't figure out what. any ideas?

Comment: Also, it seems the lines DO appear, but not 100% correct, i cant select them, there seems to be something wrong with them. When i watch the lines 'properties' theres errors at 'acadobject' and at 'compoundobjecttransform'

Answer (score 0):

You need to :

```
trat.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(blort, true);
```

Before:

```
trat.Commit();
```